# Is it possible to install Citadel on Fedora server 24?

Tags: mta, fedora-24

I would like to try to install **Citadel** on **Fedora 24**. Is there a way to do this? I looked at Citadel's website and I could find instructions on how to install it on Fedora 23. Is there a way to build the solution locally on my machine?

Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, you mean [this Citadel](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php), right?

Comment: Did you try the instructions for F23? Did they work? What problems did you experience?

Comment: hello, yes I mean that citadel. I tried installing from the f23 repo. I think there was some libraries missing.